# Shopping Cart URL Structure

Tags: google-analytics, url, analytics, shopping-cart

In regards to URL structure when it comes to guests and authenticated users, am I able to track traffic associated with both paths, but at the same time track total conversions going through the shopping cart?

I have set up the following URL structure:

**Authenticated users follow this path:**

```
/cart
/checkout
/checkout-confirmation-ty
```

**Guests go like such:**

```
/cart
/checkout-guest
/checkout-confirmation-guest-ty
```

1. can I track the authenticated and guest users separately?
2. is this possible with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 3):

Setup custom goal paths. Since your URL's are static it's easy to create two goal sets one for authenticated users another for guests then create custom reports to get total conversions. Here are the instructions from Google. [How to Setup Goals in Google Analytics](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-setup-goals-in-google-analytics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#sessionLevel) see the section "Session-level Custom Variables" , or only set value to [_trackPageview()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) method.

See you! :)